# "Fascinating" holiday hat

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014, secret-hats

So... I just got a new hat today.
I can't understand how I got it, and since it's secret hat (which is also weird), it doesn't show up in the "WinterBash 2014" page.
It's called "Fascinating" hat, and I'm wearing it now.

Any idea?