# Newly-migrated questions lack information in their timestamp on the front page

Tags: bug, migration

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246346/fascinating-holiday-hat) just got migrated here from Meta.SF:

[image]

The timestamp just reads "5m ago", without any indication of the user responsible or what action was performed. I imagine this could be partly due to the fact that the user whose post was migrated isn't registered here on Meta.SE.

This should probably read at least "modified 5m ago" (if we're going to stick with "modified", "asked", and "answered" as the only options for that, anyway), if not "modified 5m ago EliadTech".

Comment: ...or even "imported 5m ago".

Comment: Eh, how didn't I notice it before... :D

Comment: The author doesn't have a profile on MSE, which is contributing to this.