# Do newly-migrated post requires an actual "edit" to show username and time on the Meta.SE main page?

Tags: discussion, migration, recent-activity, timestamps

Please do not mark this question as duplicate of [Newly-migrated questions lack information in their timestamp on the front page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246347/newly-migrated-questions-lack-information-in-their-timestamp-on-the-front-page) as that question is after finding *why* the newly-migrated question does not show timestamp on the main page. I have spent good amount of time on searching this but couldn't find anything.

My question is about the event (i.e. "edit" in this case) that made the newly-migrated post to display its relevant information such as username and time on the Meta.SE main page.

Here is my observation of the post [How are audit questions decided](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261212/how-are-audit-questions-decided) which was migrated from meta.serverfault.com
Note: Timestamps are taken from the post's [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/261212/revisions).

- The question appeared on Meta.SE main page showing just "55 secs ago" (Chrome, whereas FF shows "migrated here 55 secs ago") in the status area. Here is the screenshot of the same. The actual event time (as per revision history) is 2015-07-22 22:05:20Z

> [image]

- A minute later, the [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/261212/revisions) makes an entry stating "Post Migrated Here from meta.serverfault.com" at 2015-07-22 22:06:24Z
- At 2015-07-22 22:07:18Z user was given "[Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/299850/drifter104?tab=reputation)".
- And 6 minutes later, the post gets closed as "**duplicate**" by ShadowWizard at 2015-07-22 22:11:27Z. Upon reloading the main page, it does shows the post with "[duplicate]" word at the end in the title. Here is the screenshot of it:

> [image]

- Now almost 13 mins are passed but the main page of Meta.SE had no info. about the post's username and time. All it showed "13 mins ago" (or "migrated here 13 mins ago" in the status area. Here is the screenshot:

> [image]

- Then, at 2015-07-22 22:22:30Z OP made an "**[edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/261212/revisions)**" to the post. And upon reloading the main page it appeared with "modified" status along with username and time.
  Sorry, no screenshot of this. I missed it, but I remember seeing it. I am sure high-reps and moderators can recreate/simulate this on a newly-migrated post.

As you can see from the above chained event, Meta.SE main page did not display user info. and time even after OP's profile got created (after migration) or the post was marked as "duplicate" by ShadowWizard. These two events were *not enough* to update the post information on the Meta.SE main page.

So, my question is do newly-migrated question requires an actual **edit** to display the username and time on the Meta.SE main page? Will the user info. and time show just "xx mins ago" (or "migrated here xx mins ago" - FF) if no "edit" made to post? Or, is there something else that can do this? Can anyone please explain.